# Scrapy how to make async request from FSFilesStore/media pipeline?

Tags: python, async-await, scrapy, twisted

What I need is to stat file based on head request, instead of downloading entire file. File is video(can be big), always have same name. Can determine update based on size and update change from head.

Code:

```
import treq
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FSFilesStore

class FSFilesStoreDBCacheExtended(FSFilesStore):

    async def stat_file(self, path, info):
        try:
            head_resp = await treq.head('https://google.com')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)  # ConnectError here
            raise e

        size = int(head_resp.headers['content-length'])
        mod_timestamp = head_resp.headers['last-modified']
        # ... do some stuff

        return super().stat_file(path, info)


class ImageDownload(FilesPipeline):

    def __init__(self, store_uri, download_func=None, settings=None):
        self.STORE_SCHEMES[''] = FSFilesStoreDBCacheExtended
        self.STORE_SCHEMES['file'] = FSFilesStoreDBCacheExtended
        super().__init__(store_uri, download_func, settings)
```

`treq` fails with error:

`[<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]`

Most probably `async` is not allowed here.

There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624350/making-a-non-blocking-http-request-from-scrapy-pipeline), but there is no access to crawler and spider and it looks very hacky: don't want media process logic to be in spider.

**Question**: how to make non blocking HTTP call from `stat_file` method with `treq` or any other lib or by scrapy tool?

Comment: It's not clear what the question here is.  You say you want to do something and you gave a code fragment.  What's the connection?  Does the code the fragment is derived from fail?  Do you not like the abstractions?  You also mention the fragment has poor exception handling behavior (but it does not fail silently as you suggest - it fails with a print()) is the question about how to improve this behavior?

Comment: first you should run code without `try/except` to see FULL error message - it may help to see problem.